# The Operator "NOT IN" Does Not Work In tax_query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

I'm trying to alter the search functionality of a WooCommerce store so when a user makes a query that matches a `product_tag` slug it returns the products that don't have that product tag assigned.

The logic behind this is showing all the products without gluten to a user who searches for "gluten".

My code is almost working except for the *operator* parameter.

I'm throwing this query:

```
http://example.com/?s=gluten
```

**This function returns all the products tagged as the search query:**

```
function menta_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('s'), 'product_tag');
    if ( $term && !is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
        $tax_query = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_tag',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => $term->slug,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
        );
        $query->tax_query->queries[] = $tax_query;
        $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = $query->tax_query->queries;
     }
}}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'menta_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

**But if I change the operator to NOT IN, I get no results:**

```
function menta_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('s'), 'product_tag');
    if ( $term && !is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
        $tax_query = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_tag',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => $term->slug,
                'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
        );
        $query->tax_query->queries[] = $tax_query;
        $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = $query->tax_query->queries;
     }
}}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'menta_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

The products are correctly tagged, and there are products without the *gluten* tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you need an array for the terms - although I'm not sure why it would work with "IN" and not with "NOT IN"... But I'd try this:

```
function menta_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('s'), 'product_tag');
    if ( $term && !is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
        $tax_query = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_tag',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => array($term->slug),
                'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
        );
        $query->tax_query->queries[] = $tax_query;
        $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = $query->tax_query->queries;
        $query->set('tax_query', $query->tax_query->queries);
     }
}}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'menta_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but I've just tried that and the query still doesn't return results

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. Well in the past, I've also sometimes had to add `$query->set('tax_query', $query->tax_query->queries);` -- see my updated answer.

Comment: You could also debug the query to see what WP builds off your filter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis

Comment: I'm getting unconsistent results, but at least I have a base for debugging queries. I'm marking your answer as accepted as further problems might be caused by external factors, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the answer by @nibnut, I recommend to check first if there is some tax_query in the Query, so you do not overwrite them:

```
$query->tax_query->queries      = (array) $query->get( 'tax_query' );
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/252806)